# Add new custom field column

Tags: wordpress, profile, civicrm.settings.php, admin

I've created a custom field that saves **"Registration"** in a contact type in CiviCRM. I would like to display this custom field in a new column in the search results.
Installing in WordPress allows me to modify the plugin file, but I have had some errors when trying to add the code snippet.

```
$headers['summary'] = array('name' =>
```

Comment: Have you tried SearchKit?

Comment: It's just one field that I need to add to the traditional search. If you use SearchKit, you will have to create a complete new search interface.

Comment: Depends what search you want to replace, but in many cases it's not hard to replace with SK and it's the direction all searches are going.

Comment: curious - what is the 'registration' that you are recording? wondering if there is a more standard way of doing what you are doing

Answer (score 4):

If you're talking about the contact basic and advanced search results, you can add the field to a profile and set that to be used at `Administer > Customise Data and Screens > Search Preferences > Default Contact Search Profiles`